# How to display a dataset

Tags: dataset

I'm not good with R at all, so I asked for advice. Thanks!

I want to display a dataset created by a function, but once I ask "print(df)" or "print(head(df))" I get in return:

> print(head(df))
> 1 function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE)
> 2 {
> 3     if (missing(ncp))
> 4         .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
> 5     else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
> 6 }

How can I display my 'df' to import it as a csv file from R?

Follow the function a colleague of mine wrote to create the dataset called 'df'.

get_tair_rh <- function(site, TT_list, tt, mydata_4D, mydata_59){

## Extract data

df4D <- subset(mydata_4D, mydata_4D$TT_ID %in% TT_list, select=c(Datetime, TT_ID, Timestamp, Tair, RH))
df59 <- subset(mydata_59, mydata_59$TT_ID %in% TT_list, select=c(Datetime, TT_ID, Timestamp, Tair, RH))
df4D$Tair <- df4D$Tair/10
df <- rbind(df4D,df59)
rm(df4D,df59)